# Parsing JSON multidimensional array with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to parsing some data from a Json File but I'm getting some problems.

This is my sample Data from the JSON file
[image: Data Source]

And this is my code:

```
foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
{
    JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
    DadosLocaisInteresse group = 
        new DadosLocaisInteresse(
            groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
            groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
            groupObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
            groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
            groupObject["Description"].GetString(),
            groupObject["Latitude"].GetNumber(),
            groupObject["Longitude"].GetNumber()
    );

    foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
    {
        JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();

        group.Items.Add(
            new DadosLocaisInteressePontos(
                itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                itemObject["Content"].GetString(),
                itemObject["ItemLatitude"].GetNumber(),
                itemObject["ItemLongitude"].GetNumber())
        );

        foreach (JsonValue galeriaValue in itemObject["Galerias"].GetArray())
        {
            JsonObject galeriaObject = galeriaValue.GetObject();
            ItemsGaleria galeria = 
                new ItemsGaleria(
                    galeriaObject["UniqueID"].GetString(),
                    galeriaObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                    galeriaObject["ImagePath1"].GetString()
            );                           

        }
    }
    this.Groups.Add(group);
}
```

The Groups and Items Arrays works just fine.
The problem is that I can't get the data from the "Galeria Array"...
What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: It's `Galeria` in JSON and `Galerias` in your code.

Comment: @JossefHarush my exception is:
An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below mentioned method to DeserializeObject

You have to create a class which can contain the properties like :

```
 public class Grp
{

    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    private List<item> _Items=new List<item>();

    public List<item> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set { _Items = value; }
    }


}
 public class item
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can add the using Newtonsoft.Json; to DeserializeObject;

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Grp>(s);
```